# Dynamic control in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, dynamic

This is my code for dynamic textbox controls in button click event. The code is working well. If i click the button 3 times, it is generated 3 text boxes. But I have no idea to assign text box values to a variable. I dont know the names of dynamic generated controls. if i want to add value to 3rd text box, how to do it?

```
Dim txtBx As TextBox
Static x As Integer
Static i As Integer

txtBx = New TextBox

txtBx.Location = New Point(10, 10 + x)
txtBx.Size = New Size(100, 20)

i = i + 1
x = x + 20

Me.Controls.Add(txtBx)
```

if i create normal textbox i can do it with,

```
TextBox3.Text = "Some value"
```

But I dont know to do this for dynamic controls.

Comment: Access them via `Controls` collection or save references of controls into `List<T>` or reference vars.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example, storing the references in a List(Of Textbox):

`Public Class Form1`

```
Private tbList As New List(Of TextBox)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim tb As TextBox
    Dim n As Integer

    n = tbList.Count + 1
    tb = New TextBox
    With tb
        .Location = New Point(10, 10 + (n * 20))
        .Name = "dynTB" & n.ToString
        .Size = New Size(100, 20)
    End With
    Me.tbList.Add(tb)
    Me.Controls.Add(tb)

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    ' Testing:
    If Me.tbList.Count >= 3 Then Me.tbList(2).Text = "This is textbox 3"
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: This is what i needed. I got an idea from this code. Now i can complete big part of my project. Than you very much KekuSemau.